# Changing \beforepoemtitleskip in memoir with verse package

Tags: memoir, verse

I would like to increase the vertical space before the titles in a book of poetry that I am setting, but there is a seeming conflict between `\setlength{\beforepoemtitleskip}` and `\setlrmarginsandblock`.

```
\documentclass[ebook]{memoir}

\begin{filecontents}{memory.tex}
\poemtitle{memory poem}
\settowidth{\versewidth}{the pearly silver shell}

\begin{verse}[\versewidth]
I want a poem to kiss me\\
deep inside\\
the pearly silver shell\\
of soul\\
\end{verse}

\begin{verse}[\versewidth]
erase my nightmares\\
turn them into\\
delinquent good deeds\\
\end{verse}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{zref-abspage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ccicons}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{verse}

\chapterstyle{dash}


\setlrmarginsandblock{*}{0.75in}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{0.75in}{0.75in}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{\oddsidemargin}

\setlength{\beforepoemtitleskip}{2.0in}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{plain}
\aliaspagestyle{part}{empty}

\mainmatter

\book*{\textsc{I Want A Poem}}

\include{memory}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a workaround.

Replace

```
\setlength{\beforepoemtitleskip}{2.0in}
```

with

```
\let\oldpoemtitle\poemtitle
\renewcommand{\poemtitle}{\vspace*{2.0in}\oldpoemtitle}
```

so to redefine `\poemtitle` to have `2.0in` space before it.

The starred version of `\vspace` ensures the spacing even when no text comes before it in the page.

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[ebook]{memoir}

\begin{filecontents}{memory.tex}
\poemtitle{memory poem}
\settowidth{\versewidth}{the pearly silver shell}

\begin{verse}[\versewidth]
I want a poem to kiss me\\
deep inside\\
the pearly silver shell\\
of soul\\
\end{verse}

\begin{verse}[\versewidth]
erase my nightmares\\
turn them into\\
delinquent good deeds\\
\end{verse}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{zref-abspage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ccicons}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{verse}

\chapterstyle{dash}


\setlrmarginsandblock{*}{0.75in}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{0.75in}{0.75in}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{\oddsidemargin}

\let\oldpoemtitle\poemtitle
\renewcommand{\poemtitle}{\vspace*{2.0in}\oldpoemtitle}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{plain}
\aliaspagestyle{part}{empty}

\mainmatter

\book*{\textsc{I Want A Poem}}

\include{memory}


\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]